# Filter list view based on foreign key of another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have three models, subjects, topics and study days. I want to display the study days in a list view but just show study days with different topics connected to the same subject.

This is my model structure

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

 
class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

 
class StudyDay(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I have tried this in one of the views and it filters correctly but it removes the data previously showing up associated with the study day, so it does not work correctly.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['study'] = context['study'].filter(student=self.request.user)
        context['study'] = Topic.objects.filter(subject=3) # This is the line where I try to filter
        return context
```

So the question is, is there any way for me to filter through the objects in the StudyDay model based on which subject the topic in the study day belongs to?

Comment: I'm curious, will you only ever have one topic per study day?  Or would you like your study day to include multiple topics?

Comment: A studyday could have multiple topics

Comment: Have you considered using a ManyToMany field for the topic?  If so, that's a different query, and I can help you out.

Comment: No I have not and that is because the topics get listed in a table, where the days the user have studied that topic are the different columns in the table. If I have thought about this correctly, a ManyToMany field would make it possible for a user to create the same row twice and this should not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to use `__` (double underscore) to access the attributes of your ForeignKeys in `filter`. See the [Django docs about filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

So in this specific case you could get StudyDays by Subject if you do:

```
context['study'] = StudyDay.objects.filter(student=self.request.user, topic__subject__pk=3)
```